# Paste column to existing file in a loop

Tags: bash, shell, unix, paste

I am using the paste command in a bash loop to add new columns to a CSV-file. I would like to reuse the CSV-file. Currently I am using a temporary file to accomplish this:

```
while [ $i -le $max ]
    do
        # create text from grib2
        wgrib2 -d 1.$(($i+1)) -no_header myGribFile.grb2 -text tmptxt.txt

        #paste to temporary file
        paste -d, existingfile.csv tmptxt.txt > tmpcsv.csv  

        #overwrite old csv with new csv
        mv tmpcsv.csv existingfile.csv

        ((i++))
    done
```

After adding some columns the copy is getting slow, because the file is becoming bigger and bigger (every `tmptxt.txt` has about 2 MB, adding to approx 100 MB).

A `tmptxt.txt` is a plain txt-file with one column and one value per row:

```
1
2
3
.
.
```

The `existingfile.csv` would then be

```
1,1,x
2,2,y
3,3,z
.,.,.
.,.,.
```

Is there any way to use the paste command to add a column to an existing file? Or is there any other way?

Thanks

Comment: One alternative would be to collect the columns that you're going to add into intermediate chunks (ie. files with more than one column), so paste could run faster afterwards. Is this feasable for you?

Comment: If you include the "code to create the tmptxt.txt". We could actually help you.

Comment: it would be: wgrib2 -d 1.$(($i+1)) -no_header myGribFile.grb2 -text tmptxt.txt

Comment: @JanitoVaqueiroFerreiraFilho sounds good. You are thinking of something like a tree, am I right? I have never done this before and I am thinking of a lot of if's and else's. Do you know a simple approach for that?

Comment: Honestly, no =(. I would try with a nested while loop, the external loop defining how many files to join, and the internal loop actually pasting them together.

Comment: The solution provided by @German Garcia works fine, i guess i will stick with that and try your suggestion if further improvement will be needed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would it be feasible to split the operation in 2 ? One step for generating *all* the intermediate files; and another for generating *all* the final output file. The idea is to avoid rereading and rewriting over and over the final file.

The changes to the script would be something like this:

```
while [ $i -le $max ]
do
    n=$(printf "%05d" $i)    # to preserve lexical order if $max > 9
    # create text from grib2
    wgrib2 -d 1.$(($i+1)) -no_header myGribFile.grb2 -text tmptxt$n.txt
    ((i++))
done

#make final file
paste -d, existingfile.csv tmptxt[0-9]*.txt > tmpcsv.csv  

#overwrite old csv with new csv
mv tmpcsv.csv existingfile.csv
```

Comment: Great, now the script takes half of the time. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @bennos: you're welcome. It's great to know about the speed improvement. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the number of lines output by the program is constant and is equal to number of lines in `existingfile.csv` (which should be the case since you are using `paste`)

Disclaimer: I'm not exactly sure if this would speed things up (depending on whether io redirection `>>` writes to the file exactly once or not). Anyway give it a try and let me know.

So the basic idea is

1. append the output in one go after the loop is done (note the change: wgrib now prints to `-` which is `stdout`)
2. use awk to move every `linenum` rows (`linenum` being the number of lines in `existingfile.csv`) to the end to the first `linenum` rows

   Save to `tempcsv.csv` (because I can't find a way to save in the same file)
3. rename to / overwrite `existingfile.csv`

.

```
while [ $i -le $max ]; do
  # create text from grib2
  wgrib2 -d 1.$(($i+1)) -no_header myGribFile.grb2 -text -

  ((i++))
done >> existingfile.csv

awk -v linenum=4 '
  { array[FNR%linenum]=array[FNR%linenum]","$0 } 
  END { for(i=1;i<linenum;i++) print array[i%linenum] }
' existingfile.csv > tempcsv.csv

mv tempcsv.csv existingfile.csv
```

If this is how I imagine it would work (internally), you should have 2 writes to `existingfile.csv` instead of `$max` number of writes. So hopefully this would speed things up.

Comment: The approach sounds good and I also found a faster way to get the .csv without the while-loop (with wgrib2). But still awk slowed it down and i ended up with approximately the same times in three different approaches (everything between 24 and 27 seconds). Thanks for your help!

Comment: You mean even with `wgrib2`-`paste`-`mv` (without `while`) you are still getting around the same time?

Comment: Yes,  `wgrib2 -no_header myGribFile.grb2 -text existingfile.csv`(without the iterating) produces a file like the ´<<

Comment: Messed up previous comment!
I mean, that my described approach, your approach and another one with `wgrib2`-`awk`-`mv` (without `while`) are consuming the same time.